# How to display validation error messages with Simple_form but without model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form-for

I use Simple_form in my Rails 4 application.

How can I display error messages in a view that is not tied to a model ?

I want to have the same result than in other views based on models.

For now, this is the code in the view :

```
<%= simple_form_for(:registration, html: { role: 'form' }, :url => registrations_path) do |f| %>

  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= f.input :name, :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
  <%= f.input :email, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

In a 'normal' view (i.e. with a model) the line `<%= f.error_notification %>` display errors.

What should I do in my controller to initialize something used by Simple_form to display errors ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Simple Form does not support this functionality "out of the box". But you can add it with a "monkey patch" in an initializer like this (disclaimer - this appears to work for my simple test case but has not been thoroughly tested):

```
// Put this code in an initializer, perhaps at the top of initializers/simple_form.rb
module SimpleForm
  module Components
    module Errors
      def has_errors?
        has_custom_error? || (object && object.respond_to?(:errors) && errors.present?)
      end

      def errors
        @errors ||= has_custom_error? ? [options[:error]] : (errors_on_attribute + errors_on_association).compact
      end
    end
  end
end

module SimpleForm
  class ErrorNotification
    def has_errors?
      @options[:errors] || (object && object.respond_to?(:errors) && errors.present?)
    end
  end
end
```

And then you can add errors to your form like this (note you indicate whether to show the error notification by setting 'errors: true', you would have to perform your own check to decide if there are errors present, and add the errors dynamically):

```
=simple_form_for :your_symbol do |f|
  =f.error_notification errors: true
  =f.input :item1, as: :string, error: "This is an error on item1"
  =f.input :item2, as: :string, error: "This is an error on item2"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `simple_form_for` helper must wrap a model. But just because we say this doesn't mean it has to be an ActiveRecord model that's backed by a database table. You're free to create models that aren't backed by a database. In Rails 3+ the way to do this is to have your class include the components that you need from `ActiveModel`. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123858/how-to-create-activerecord-tableless-model-in-rails-3) explains how to do this with an example (and I'm sure there's many others out there). Once you have a model that includes `ActiveModel::Validation` you can add to the `errors` collection and then the `f.error_notification` statement will output the errors as you're used to in table-backed models.

TL;DR: Create a non-ActiveRecord, non-table-backed model then treat it like a regular old model and the form should do the right thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's possible to use Simple_form without a model : just use ````:symbol```` as first argument. Actually, my controller/view work very well, and I just want to display error messages (generated by my controller) as a view based on a model do. Anyway, thanks for your idea, I will look this solution.

Comment: Ahh, good to know. Didn't realize that about simple_form. Still, the `error_notification` helper most likely is looking for an `errors` method on the wrapped object. It makes sense that a symbol wouldn't respond to this. I wonder if you could have the form wrap a `Struct` object which does respond to `errors`. Perhaps, but it still seems like a non-database-backed model would be better to me.

Answer (score -1):

Use client_side_validations gem , it is simple , and you've to do only -

```
<%= simple_form_for(:registration, html: { role: 'form' }, :url => registrations_path) , :validate => true do |f| %>
```

But you need to add validations in model also.

Comment: Thanks. I will test this. But I don't have a model. Only a controller and the view.